# How does one achieve a non-stick layer over a copper plate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

We normally perform the process of coating of aluminum on BOPP under vacuum.

In this process, we use a copper material holder to electrically evaporate the aluminum. With this, the balance aluminum vapors get cooled down and sticks to the holder.

Due to this sticking, we need to remove the aluminum by scraping it off which consumes a lot of time. Is there a way to make the holder non-stick to eliminate this process from the overall process?

Comment: I assume "scrapping" meant scraping the metal off. Feel free to correct if it was wrong.